# MYSQL one to many: acessing the primary key from the fitst table, not the Fk from the second

Tags: mysql

A mysql one to many question: various products and where I sell them.  I have a variety of products that I can sell, and several locations to sell them.  I have a products table with a Primary Key: product_id.  I have a locations table with PK location_id and a field product_id to link to the products table.

So, SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN locations on product_id.

I got an ambiguous column error. That doesn't make sense, they should line up.

So: SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN locations on products.product_id = locations.product_id.

That worked.

Here's the problem: there are many products I can get but don't currently sell. Some products have no locations.  To create a link to add a location, I need the product_id.  If I print out $row['product_id'] I am getting the product ids from the locations table, which is blank if they are unsold.  I need the product ids from the first table.

This can't be an unusual situation.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in your SELECT statement that you want to use the `product_id` from the `products` table.  Here is a sample of what I am talking about ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca9a9/1/0)):

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.description, p.unit_of_measure, l.location
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN locations l on l.product_id = p.product_id
```

As you can see for `product_id` 3 there is no location but yet I am still displaying the `product_id`.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports the `using` clause, so you can write the first version as:

```
SELECT *
FROM products LEFT JOIN
     locations
     USING (product_id);
```

Without the `using` clause, MySQL needs to know the table where a column comes from.  Because there are two tables with the same column name, MySQL is confused.

This also has the advantage that the `*` only includes the `product_id` column once, not twice.

Comment: Are you sure it supports it.  It doesn't work in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca9a9/4).

Comment: @Linger . . . Oops.  I had left out the parentheses.  It does indeed work:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca9a9/6.